# A question about the derivative of $\arctan(f(x))$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

We all know that:

$$ \int{\frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2 + 1}} dx  = \arctan(f(x)) + c.$$

But what happens if we change the $1$ in the denominator? For example:
$$\int{\frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2 + c}} dx. \qquad (c \in \mathbb R)$$

Answer (score 4):

Then you can use a function $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{c}}$, $(c>0)$ and everything will turn out nicely ...

Comment: it doesn't if $c < 0$...

Comment: You're right of course, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: +1, both for giving the nice hint and for writing it down before me.

Comment: If $c=0$, use $-1/f(x)$. If $c<0$, use $-\mathrm{artanh}(f(x)/\sqrt{-c})/\sqrt{-c}$.